# cc1plus.exe: out of memory allocating 536875007 bytes

Tags: qt, memory, qml, qr-code

I tried to run my source code. It was working fine before, but suddenly I got an error:

```
cc1plus.exe: out of memory allocating 536875007 bytes
Makefile.Debug:1798: recipe for target 'debug/qrc_qml.o' failed
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory '/path/Source/source'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug/qrc_qml.o] Error 1
Makefile:36: recipe for target 'debug' failed
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
12:19:08: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.10.0\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project Qt_NGI (kit: Desktop Qt 5.10.0 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step "Make"
12:19:08: Elapsed time: 01:1
```

Comment: Vineesh, when code causes problems, you need to include your ***code!!*** Just a heads-up for next time to avoid getting closed and/or deleted.

Comment: How can I add the code for the memory issue.  That is why I added the error log

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This thread solved my issue](https://forum.qt.io/topic/62655/cc1plus-exe-out-of-memory-60mb-encrypted-resource-file/8)

Added `"CONFIG += resources_big" into *.pro` file.